# [iOS][Android]: How to hide the status bar with platform UNO?

Tags: uno-platform

How would I hide the status bar on top of the screen in iOS (and Android).

Believe, [Xamarin.Forms](https://dotnetco.de/hide-status-bar-in-xamarin-forms-for-ios-and-android/#:%7E:text=Open%20your%20Info.,appearance%20%E2%80%93%20Type%20Boolean%20%E2%80%93%20Value%20No) has a way to do that. But how would I do that with Platform UNO?

Thanks in advance

Dierk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uno Platform supports the UWP `StatusBar` API on Android and iOS, you can hide and show the status bar in the following manner:

```cs
        private void HideStatusBar()
        {
            var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () => await statusBar.HideAsync()
            );
        }

        private void ShowStatusBar()
        {
            var statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();

            Windows.UI.Xaml.Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                async () => await statusBar.ShowAsync()
            );
        }
```