# How to change the color for the status bar and the swipe bar section?

Tags: ios, uno-platform

How would I change the color of status bar section (top of screen) and the swipe bar section (bottom of screen) [as per image here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64501502/ios-how-to-leave-space-for-top-and-bottom-status-bar/64503622#64503622) (where both sections are LightBlue)?

Preferably I wanted to set a different color on top than on bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question already was answered by the sample on link above: setting .Background of the parent UIElement is sufficient